# Node.js/Sockets - User connects, it loads previous messages but it loads messages to all other chat users instead of the one that just connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

so I am new to node.js, I am making chat.
Basically I have two files: server.js (server side) and script.js (client side).
in server side I put this:

in server.js:

```
socket.on('previousMessages', function (data){
    db.query("SELECT * FROM messages", function (error, results, fields) {
    for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
    var obj = results[i];
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', {

        'message' : "hellow",

        'pseudo' : "arleitiss"

    });
    //console.log("break");
}
    });
    });
```

in script.js:

```
function addMessage(msg, pseudo){
    $("#chatEntries").append('<div class="message"><p>' +
     pseudo + ' : ' + msg + '</p></div>');
}

    socket.on('message', function(data){
        addMessage(data['message'], data['pseudo']);
    });
```

So when user logins, enters his nickname, it loads all previous messages from database. 
Then its' supposed to load them in chat for only that user who connected, but instead: it ignores the user that just connected and loads all messages for other chat users.

So how do I go about fixing this?

Oh yeah and don't mind that I am not using results yet, I am just testing first using basic variables.

Comment: you are doing a SELECT * FROM messages, i don't see any where clause, saying that where id in (array_of_online_ids)

Comment: that's not the point, thats just loading messages into chat room that were posted before used connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server you use *socket.**broadcast**.emit* what emit a message to all **OTHER** sockets.

Just do *socket.emit*.

Comment: That worked very well. Also learned important thing, I thought socket.broadcast.emit is same as socket.emit.

so socket.broadcast.emit is for all connected clients and socket.emit is just for the client side? 

Can socket.emit be always used to parse variables between server and client himself?

Comment: The emit method is used to send data by the socket. 

Client-side you can use emit on the socket object to send data to the server. But server-side you can use it on the server objet to send data to all connected client or on the socket object to send data to the single client connected to this socket. 'broadcast' is a "flag" on the socket object what use to broadcast a message to everyone except the current socket. 

http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages